# How to scroll a TTabSheet

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tpagecontrol, tscrollbox, ttabsheet

I'd like to scroll an individual TabSheet within a PageControl if the height of the sheet becomes less than a value.

If I put a ScrollBox on the TabSheet, the themed background of the TabSheet is not painted (it's overwritten by the single color background of the scrollbox).

I've been trying to find / create a transparent scrollbox component with no luck. Any other ideas?

I'm using Delphi 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting a panel inside the tabsheet and then the scroll box inside that

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work either... Same problem.

Comment: Set ParentBackground of scrollbox to true.

Comment: It's set to true but that doesn't help - the themed background of a TabSheet under Windows XP is not a single color, it's a gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, TMS has a transparent scrollbox component called "TAdvScrollBox" that works with themed tabsheets too:
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asb.asp

Maybe this will help somebody:
There is a small bug with the component that turns the ParentCtl3d property to false causing ListViews to be rendered with a black border instead of a 3d one. It's easy to fix by setting ParentCtl3d to true programmatically on FormCreate.